# Getting the Error "Input string was not in a correct format" on DataAdapter Update Command

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, sqlite

I have an application that uses a sqlite3 database with multiple tables. There are a few that need to have foreign keys. I can load the data into a dataset and bind it to my controls. Then when users make changes or add records they are saved to the dataset and I call the DataAdapter.Update. The problem I'm running into is that I always get the error "Input string was not in a correct format" when I update the database from my dataset. I'll include screenshots of my database design, and my code.

The code runs fine but the try block catches the error, and the database doesn't get updated.

[EIData Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgKoB.png)[Contacts Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow2un.png)[Accounts Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDQ3l.png)[EIData Design with FK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRh9s.png)

```vb
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Module Get_Data

    Dim mycon As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source = 
    C:\Users\Public\Documents\Livestock Data\Livestock.db;Version=3")
    Dim fdata As DataSet = Form1.fdata
    Dim EIadapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter

    Sub GetEIData()
    'SELECT Command to fill Dataset

    EIadapter.SelectCommand = New SQLiteCommand("SELECT EIData.Date, 
    Accounts.Account, Contacts.Name, EIData.Description, EIData.Amount, 
    EIData.Person, EIData.GPID, EIData.EI, EIData.rowid 
    FROM EIData 
    LEFT JOIN Accounts ON EIData.Account = Accounts.Id
    LEFT JOIN Contacts ON EIData.Name = Contacts.Id", mycon)
    EIadapter.Fill(fdata, "EIData")

    'INSERT command to insert added rows to database
    EIadapter.InsertCommand = New SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO EIData(Date, 
    Account, Name, Description, Amount, Person, GPID, EI)
    VALUES(@Date,(SELECT Id FROM Accounts WHERE Account = @Account),(SELECT 
    Id 
    FROM Contacts WHERE Name = 
    @Name),@Description,@Amount,@Person,@GPID,@EI)", 
    mycon)
    With EIadapter.InsertCommand
        .Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Text, 10, "Date")
        .Parameters.Add("@Account", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Account")
        .Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Name")
        .Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, 
    "Description")
        .Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Decimal, 10, "Amount")
        .Parameters.Add("@Person", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Person")
        .Parameters.Add("@GPID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "GPID")
        .Parameters.Add("EI", SqlDbType.Bit, 2, "EI")
    End With
    'Fills dataset table
    EIadapter.Fill(fdata, "EIData")
    End Sub


    Sub updateEI()
    Try
        EIadapter.Update(fdata.Tables("EIData"))
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: It's hard to say what for sure but there's something in there that is a `String` that you are treating as another type and the required implicit conversion is failing. We don't have the data so we can't easily check but you need to look closely at that.

Comment: That said, I would suggest that you're going about this wrong in the first place. For instance, I would not be getting the `Contacts.Name` value with that query. I would just get the foreign key value and then get the primary key and `Name` values from the `Contacts` table into another `DataTable`. You can then bind that both `DataTables` to a `DataGridView` or `ComboBox` such that the user sees the text values while only primary and foreign key values are used under the hood. That would simplify your SQL and probably fix this issue before it happened.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I guess I'll admit I haven't heard of loading data that way. I just started working with foreign keys and have been having some problems to say the least. It seems no matter what I do I have the tendency to get some sort of error whenever I try to insert or update data. Maybe I'm doing it all wrong?

Comment: [Check this out](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476) as an example of how to load two separate tables into a combined UI. You can do basically the same thing with an individual record loaded into `TextBox` and `ComboBox` controls.

Comment: OK, What I ended up doing is using a stored view in my database. Its actually quite easy to do it that way. Load data from the view, and save it to the parent tables.